# Capturar música em execução em app alheio

Tags: java, android

Olá, no Facebook tem um botão que mostra qual música do Spotify está rodando.
Tem como fazer isso no meu app?
Já procurei informações mas não encontro como fazer isso no Android.
O que quero é que ele capture dentro do Spotify aberto o *título* e *artista* da música em execução.

Comment: Acho que isso tem que ver se o spotify disponibiliza via API.

Comment: E você já tentou alguma coisa? Já deu uma olhada na API do Spotify, como o colega @diegofm menciona? Vc diz que não encontra como fazer isso "no Android", mas já encontrou como fazer isso em outra plataforma? Forneça esses detalhes pois eles te ajudam a conseguir uma resposta melhor e mais rapidamente.

Answer (score 1):

O exemplo abaixo mostra como receber notificaçoes da media sendo executada no Spotify. Para que isso funcione você precisa habilitar sua classe para que a mesma receba tais notificações e isso é feito via AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver
    android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.spotify.music.playbackstatechanged"/>
        <action android:name="com.spotify.music.metadatachanged"/>
        <action android:name="com.spotify.music.queuechanged"/>
    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

Após o recebedor ter sido cadastrado, notificações serão enviadas à classe receptora.

Voce pode receber informações de qual artista, album, trilha e duração está sendo executada.

Segue código exemplo:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static final class BroadcastTypes {
        static final String SPOTIFY_PACKAGE = "com.spotify.music";
        static final String PLAYBACK_STATE_CHANGED = SPOTIFY_PACKAGE + ".playbackstatechanged";
        static final String QUEUE_CHANGED = SPOTIFY_PACKAGE + ".queuechanged";
        static final String METADATA_CHANGED = SPOTIFY_PACKAGE + ".metadatachanged";
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // This is sent with all broadcasts, regardless of type. The value is taken from
        // System.currentTimeMillis(), which you can compare to in order to determine how
        // old the event is.
        long timeSentInMs = intent.getLongExtra("timeSent", 0L);

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(BroadcastTypes.METADATA_CHANGED)) {
            String trackId = intent.getStringExtra("id");
            String artistName = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
            String albumName = intent.getStringExtra("album");
            String trackName = intent.getStringExtra("track");
            int trackLengthInSec = intent.getIntExtra("length", 0);
            // Do something with extracted information...
        } else if (action.equals(BroadcastTypes.PLAYBACK_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            boolean playing = intent.getBooleanExtra("playing", false);
            int positionInMs = intent.getIntExtra("playbackPosition", 0);
            // Do something with extracted information
        } else if (action.equals(BroadcastTypes.QUEUE_CHANGED)) {
            // Sent only as a notification, your app may want to respond accordingly.
        }
    }
}
```

Maiores informações podem ser obtidas [aqui](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/android-media-notifications/).

Comment: O que esse código faz? Como ele funciona? Uma explicação, mesmo que simples, ajudaria muito pra que ela ficasse melhor. Os comentários estão em inglês, você também poderia tê-los traduzido. O ponto bom é que você citou a fonte. Não fui eu quem votou pra negativar, mas você só mereceria o meu +1 se melhorasse um pouco essa resposta aí.

Comment: Vou tentar entender como colocar isso no meu projeto e assim que conseguir dou meu feedback se deu certo xD

Comment: Não funcionou, será que fiz algo errado t.t
Adicionei o receiver no meu android manifest, criei a classe MyBroadcastReceiver e colei o codigo nela...
Acrescentei uma variavel
public String music_finally="";
e no on receive, apos pegar as musicas, fiz
music_finally=artistName+trackName;

E no main activy principal eu fiz assim
chamo a classe
private MyBroadcastReceiver Spotify=new MyBroadcastReceiver();
E fiz uma funcao que acada 2 segundos dá um alerta chamando a string Spotify.music_finally

Era pra retornar a musica, mas a variavel continua vazia... Será que fiz algo errado?